# OpenSSL error "assertion failed"

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I have a problem, when i use http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html , i try to Init Encryption, but always catch error like

> "OpenSSL assertion failed, evp_enc.c(282)"

Can somebody help me with this matter?

**My code:**

```
bool do_encrypt(const char *in, unsigned char *out, int *outlen, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv)
{
  int buflen, tmplen;

  EVP_CIPHER_CTX ctx;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init(&ctx);
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(&ctx, EVP_rc4(), NULL, key, iv);

  if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, out, &buflen, (unsigned char*)in, strlen(in))) // error here
    {
        return false;
  }

  if(!EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(&ctx, out + buflen, &tmplen))
    {
        return false;
  }

  buflen += tmplen;
  *outlen = buflen;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup(&ctx);

  return true;
}
```

I use `key` for test  {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}, `iv` is NULL.

Code that uses this function above:

```
int WINAPI OwnSend(SOCKET s, const char FAR *buff, int len, int flags )
{
    if(s == ServerSocket)
    {
        if(len > 0)
        {
            int outlen;
            unsigned char EncryptBuffer[5500];
            do_encrypt(buff, EncryptBuffer, &outlen, KeyTest, NULL);
            buff = (const char *) EncryptBuffer;
            return pTrampolineSend(s, buff, outlen, flags);
        }
    }
    return pTrampolineSend(s, buff, len, flags);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which call is giving the error?

Comment: i updated first post("//error here"). 
`if(!EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx, out, &buflen, (unsigned char*)in, strlen(in)))`

Answer (score 1):

The only assertion in `EVP_EncryptUpdate` is one that asserts that the buffer length is less than or equal to the block size of the encryption algorithm.

Instead of calling `strlen(in)` as the size of your input, try looping `EVP_EncryptUpdate` and each time you go through, make sure to limit the input size with:

```
int in_size_limit = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_block_size(&ctx);
```

While looping, be sure to increment the offset of the 2nd and 4th args by the number of bytes you've already encrypted:

```
if ( EVP_EncryptUpdate(&ctx,
                       out+encrypted_bytes,
                       &bytes_encrypted_this_call,
                       in+encrypted_bytes,
                       in_size_limit) != 1)
{
    /* error */
}
else
{
    encrypted_bytes += bytes_encrypted_this_call;
}
```